# Generate DACPAC diff using predefined config

Tags: sql-server, ssdt

I would like to generate a diff file based on the database vs DACPAC comparison. Currently what I am doing is extracting DACPAC from the target database and trying to create a diff file based on that (I am not sure if the DACPAC extraction is the needed step). Everything is OK until the moment when I am trying to use the same config I am using for publishing (to make sure that I am generating the script with the same configuration as I am publishing) using the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe"  
/a:Script /sf:F:\tmp\o.dacpac /tf:F:\tmp\n.dacpac /tdn:ScreenerDb  
/op:F:\tmp\ScreenerDb.sql 
/p:SqlPublishProfilePath="F:\TMap\Root\Application\Dev\Database\Financials.SQL\Financials.SQL\Publish Configs\Financials.SQL_Dev.publish.xml"
```

I am getting the following error:

> 'SqlPublishProfilePath' is not a valid argument for the 'Script' action.

To be fair, I am just trying to achieve following:

- Create a diff file based on the DB DACPAC and the real database using the same configuration as for publishing.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-2017#publish-parameters-properties-and-sqlcmd-variables), use `/Profile` instead of `/p:SqlPublishProfilePath`:

> **Parameter:**  /Profile
>   **Description:**
>   Specifies the file path to a DAC Publish Profile. The profile defines a collection of properties and variables to use when generating outputs

So this should work:

```
/Profile: "F:\TMap\Root\Application\Dev\Database\Financials.SQL\Financials.SQL\Publish Configs\Financials.SQL_Dev.publish.xml"
```